# Digitally sign latex pdf document with CA

Tags: pdf, certificate, latex, digital-signature

I would like to know, if it is possible to digitally **invisible** sign a pdf created by latex automatically after

- each time I create the document (I'm using Texnic Center) **or**
- after I created the document manually (via command line)

I know, digitally signing is possible to do with MS-word documents (I tried that with my certificate) and following google, it's probably possible with Adobe, too.

With invisible digitally signing, I don't mean to add my written signature inside the document, but rather the signing via CA certificate, so that the user knows, that I was the one creating it and that the document has not been modified or changed, but came in the form, that I was creating it.

So, what would be the best way for me to digitally sign my Latex pdf documents?

Comment: What about to do `md5sum` of the pdf file?

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer to this question on askubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/147379/how-do-i-digitally-sign-a-pdf/608449#608449

`gpg --clearsign --output=signed.pdf input.pdf`

The user can check the signature with
`gpg --verify signed.pdf`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I will try it, however I'm not sure, if I can use this in windows (I use both windows and linux, but for latex primary windows)

Comment: I just tried it on a Windows 10 machine. Be careful to check if the result is still intact. I signed a PDF file, which I created with MikTEX Latex. It was exacly like before in SumatraPDF. But AdobeReader showed only gibberish. It seems like the signing disturbed the embedded font.

Comment: I had a similar result as @Bruno in Ubuntu 18.04. After signing, Document Viewer could no longer open the PDF ("The PDF document is damaged"). It's worth noting that Chromium still could open it, and the document looked the exact same as before.

Comment: @Bruno does adobe reader consider this a validly signed document? My testing has not shown that to be true

Comment: @SultanLegend no, you can check the signature only with gpg --verify signed.pdf

Comment: Had similar result as @Bruno and Rob Hall. Did anyone find a workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information found in [this post](https://dev.gnupg.org/T5367), this solution worked for me

```
gpg --clearsign --output=signed.pdf --not-dash-escaped input.pdf
```

The `--not-dash-escaped` avoids the aforementioned display issues with pdf viewers.