# gpg --clearsign of latex-based pdf is damaged/corrupted

Tags: pdf, linux-mint, gnupg, latex, file-corruption

I am trying to digitally sign a pdf which was compiled in LaTeX. Following the suggestion to use gpg --clearsign given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1050032/digitally-sign-latex-pdf-document-with-ca?newreg=237730f6194e423b9f29ee6747650d7e) the output signed pdf is--for some reason--corrupted/damage.
Here is a MWE tex file

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

% Actual document
\begin{document}
\section*{Preamble}
\label{sec:preamble}
This is my long and boring preamble.
\end{document}
```

I am using gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19, libgcrypt 1.8.5, and pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) on Linux Mint.
Note that in the linked post there are two other users who have experienced the same issue as me. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information found in [this post](https://dev.gnupg.org/T5367), this solution worked for me

```
gpg --clearsign --output=signed.pdf --not-dash-escaped input.pdf
```

The `--not-dash-escaped` avoids the file corruption/display issues with pdf viewers.

Comment: For future LaTeX questions you could also check https://tex.stackexchange.com/, there are many knowledgeable tex users who can help/